# Array with references for a pathway to open file

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I tried the following code in order to avoid writing too much lines (since the list is long - over 134), but got error in the line which tries to open the file.

Here is an idea of the code:

```
Sub update_chemicals()
'update chemical database with macroeconomic indicators

'Dim local_main As String

Dim mylocal As Variant
Dim local_final As String

Dim myname As Variant
Dim name_final As String

'disrectories references
Dim local_1 As String
Dim local_2 As String
Dim local_3 As String
Dim local_4 As String
Dim local_5 As String

'Files
Dim name_1 As String
Dim name_2 As String
Dim name_3 As String
Dim name_4 As String
Dim name_5 As String

'Coal
local_1 = "G:\path\01. CARVAO\Carvao.V1.xlsm"
name_1 = "Carvao.V1.xlsm"

'Perlita
local_2 = "G:\path\Perlita.xlsm"
name_2 = "Perlita.xlsm"

'Diatomaceus Earth
local_3 = "G:\path\Terra_Diatomacea.xlsm"
name_3 = "Terra_Diatomacea.xlsm"

'Chloridric Acid
local_4 = "G:\path\Chloridric_Acid_v2.xlsm"
name_4 = "Chloridric_Acid_v2.xlsm"

'Hexane and Gasoline
local_5 = "G:\path\Price History - Hexane and Gasoline - PLATTS - Jan'17.xlsm"
name_5 = "Price History - Hexane and Gasoline - PLATTS - Jan'17.xlsm"


mylocal = Array("local_1", "local_2", "local_3", "local_4", "local_5")

myname = Array("name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5")

   '/////////////////////////////////////////////// COAL \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

For x = 0 To 4

    local_final = mylocal(x)
    name_final = myname(x)

        Workbooks.Open filename:=local_final
```

The error appears when I try to open the file

Could you help me out?

Comment: remove the quotations around your Array("local_1", "local_2"...) so that it is Array(local_1, local_2.......) same with the myname array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mylocal = Array("local_1", "local_2", "local_3", "local_4", "local_5")`

`myname = Array("name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5")`

It means you are literally storing local_1 & name_1 in the arrays and not the values of local_1 & name_1.

Answer (score 2):

Replace with this line, you should call the variables themselves, not the strings of the variable names:

mylocal = Array(local_1, local_2, local_3, local_4, local_5)

Comment: @Petter_Mendes Please mark this as the right answer if it worked for you. tnx